# Do I use whom or who in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, objects, whom

> Family engagement is crucial to developing children’s emergent literacy skills because children **who** are raised in homes that promote literacy do better in school and they grow up to be better readers.

Comment: There is no need to make it a direct object. People who tell jokes are fun.

Comment: *Who* is correct here and *whom* would be incorrect. In modern use, you can use *who* in all situations--*whom* is optional. (Not again: *whom* is not an option here.)